# Laravel Eloquent find vs all toArray

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I couldn't find any answers to this, so I decided to ask. I hope I'm not posting a duplicate.

I'm writing a simple console command to find tasks in database in Laravel 5. User can fire up found tasks or display them in console. So I have a RunScheduledTasksCommand class in app/Console/Commands and runOrDisplay method like this:

```
        $tasks = $this->tasks->toArray();

        if ($taskId)
        {
            $tasks = array($this->tasks->toArray());
        }

        $this->table($headers, $tasks);
```

So here, $this->tasks is my Eloquent model returned by either Task::find($taskId) or Task::all() and I want to display these tasks in a table in console.

Now, Task::find($taskId)->toArray() will produce a one dimensional array but Task::all()->toArray() will do multidimensional array. My code is working fine, I'm just curious if there is a better way to do this. Is there anything already built into Laravel 5 that will give me multidimensional array in both cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `Task::find($taskId)`, use this:

```php
Task::whereId($taskId)->get();
```

This'll ensure that you're always dealing with a `Collection` object, regardless of how many models you've got.

Comment: Wow, great! Thanks! So simple... it must be Laravel ;)